# Drop table in mysql Database with java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to drop a table from my mysql DB, I'm using this function:

*NOTE: user, pass and database are variables, I'm 100% they're correct cause I'm using them in other functions that are working.*

```
public static void deleteTable(String name) {
        String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
        String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://108.167.188.13:3306/" + database;
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user, pass);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE DATABASE " + name;
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {

            }
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try

    }
```

I receive the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'adren248_0'@'%' to database 'last_data_20_18_1_1_2015_TESTE'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
    at cleandb.CleanDB.deleteTable(CleanDB.java:65)
    at cleandb.CleanDB.main(CleanDB.java:34)
```

I just can't understand this error, I'm sure I've set the permissions correctly. Look:

[image: http://imgur.com/rLbCMse]

Comment: Is it a typo or are you trying to create a database instead of trying to drop a table?

Comment: Is your server configured to allow your user to connect to the databse?

Comment: Sorry guys, indeed this was a test I was tryinng to do, but it doesn't work either, if I change "CREATE" for "DROP" I still get this error...

Answer (score 0):

Your code states you are trying to create a database instead of dropping a table..  Maybe adding changing the query statement will do the work for you

Comment: @PM77-1: Maybe the OP added it while editing. Anyways, removed it :-)

Comment: Sorry guys, indeed this was a test I was tryinng to do, but it doesn't work either, if I change "CREATE" for "DROP" I still get this error...

Answer (score -1):

stmt.execute("DROP TABLE `your_table_name`;");

basic SQL 101

Comment: Please explain your answer, as it stands it seems at most a comment.

Comment: I don't know how can I be more clear but I'll try .........

Ques. I want to drop a table from my mysql DB.........

Ans . DROP TABLE your_table_name..............


equivalent java command :

stmt.execute("DROP TABLE your_table_name;");